# When removing poor quality content, should it be removed slowly for SEO, or all at once?

Tags: seo, content, google-ranking, google-panda-algorithm

I own a website where students share notes, articles, exams and exercises. Most of this content has bad quality, poor titles and spelling errors, but the website received a lot of traffic back in the days before Panda and Penguins.

Right now, I only allow publishing of articles with "good" quality calculated under certain parameters, but there is a lot of old, bad content still published. I'm removing these old posts slowly, in order to not confuse the Google robot, but this measure is not improving the low rankings. Would it be better if I removed all this bad content at once?

Comment: If it's hurting you now, why wait to remove it?

Comment: because if I remove it all, 3/4 of the indexed pages will be blown away at once, and Google can get suspicious about that (that's my theory)

Comment: Why would they be suspicious? What do you base this on? Content being removed is normal. Also, they already think the content is poor quality. They don't want it in their index so why keep it there and hurting yourself?

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you focus on removing bad content quickly. As Google confirmed a few days back, Google penguin is just a month away, so I believe it will help your website if you remove all the bad content at once.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the content, why can't you improvise and update it? You will have the content, traffic, and fail-safe for the algorithm.

Comment: The OP hasn't written the posts, and therefore isn't the one to rewrite them for other users.